# std::visit for variant fails to compile under clang 5

Tags: c++, c++17

The following uses of std::visit compiles properly under gcc 7.2 but fails to compile under clang 5.0. Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
#include <variant>

struct S1 {int foo() { return 0; }};
struct S2 {int foo() { return 1; }};

using V = std::variant<S1, S2>;

int  bar() {
  V v;
  return std::visit([](auto& s) { return s.foo(); }, v);
}
```

The first error is this:

```
include/c++/7.2.0/variant:238:46: error: cannot cast 'std::variant<S1, S2>' to its private base class
  'std::__detail::__variant::_Variant_storage<true, S1, S2>'
  return __get(std::in_place_index<_Np>, std::forward<_Variant>(__v)._M_u);
```

Here is a link to godbolt shows this error: https://godbolt.org/g/5iaKUm

Comment: It could be possible that libstdc++'s variant uses a non-standard feature that Clang doesn't support. It compiles with `-stdlib=libc++`.

Comment: Notice `std::get<0>(v)`, `std::get<S1>(v)`, etc. fail with essentially the same error (and fewer instantiation steps in between).

Comment: Indeed, the cause of the error seems to be the same, so we can consider this a dupe.

Answer (score 11):

This is known [bug 33222](https://llvm.org/pr33222) that seems to only affect libstdc++'s `std::variant` (and other constructs using the same combination). The problem is related to friend function to templates - see the thread for more detail.

The variant from libc++ doesn't seem to use the technique of friends that libstdc++ used, so you might want to temporarily change to libc++ in the meantime.

Small update: This has been fixed in the latest trunk.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like a clang bug. Does any one know whether the bug has been fixed in the clang dev branch?

Comment: @user2736667 As of right now, no, sorry. I'm pretty sure this will get fixed eventually though, as this is pretty serious.

Comment: @user2736667 Small update: The bug has finally been fixed! :)